# Block Search Engines and Every Thing Else

Tags: .htaccess, http

I'm using a program called ShareX which will upload screenshots I take to my web dir via ftp example: https://website.com/screenshots/

I need a way to block search engines and everyone else from browsing the screenshots dir and showing up in google images etc but have direct links work fine when I upload a screenshot to share with someone. (https://website.com/screenshots/screenshot01.jpg)

I don't upload anything super sensitive but would like the piece of mind that its off limits to everyone who doesn't know the direct path to an actual image.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable directory indexes (assuming you're running Apache)

   ```bash
   # .htaccess file in your screenshots/ directory
   Options -Indexes
   ```
2. Use a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/). Every *reputable* search engine will obey it.
3. Use a CAPTCHA (a little extreme in my opinion).